# What is the relationship of HTTP headers and directory with destructors in php?

Tags: php, destructor

I know what does destructor do in PHP OOP but one thing that i want to know that what is the relationship of HTTP headers and directory with destructor in php ?

Can anyone tell what does it mean ?

**Destructors called during the script shutdown have HTTP headers already sent. The working directory in the script shutdown phase can be different with some SAPIs (e.g. Apache).**

This is documented in **Destructor** in reference link below.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: It means "don't try to call something like `header()` in `__destruct()`" and "the state of your application may have changed during execution".

Answer (score 0):

That attempts to explain when the destructor is called *headers_sent()* will return true and it gives us the heads up that working directory might be different when the destructor is called(It may not be same as how it was during constructor or when the other methods were called)(typically working directory is where the script lives). The work around is to use absolute path or to use chdir();

So you need to be careful when you doing actions like following:

```
class Files{

    function __destruct() {
          unlink($this->logfile); // it may be wrong if it is relative path
    }    
}
```

Going back to the first part, when the destructors are called, headers is already sent. You won't able to things that depend on "header sent". For example, redirect or initializing session.